When renaming multiple properties in an entity, the EF Core migration mixes up the field names
When renaming multiple properties in an entity, the EF Core migration mixes up the field names. How can this be avoided?  Below you can see how I renamed the fields and a snippet of my auto-generated migration. I am using EF Core 8


For example, I renamed field "IsPublicAssistance" to "InitialIncomePublicAssistance", but when I ran the migration tool it decided to rename "IsPublicAssistance" as "InitialIncomeVerteranAssistance" instead!  All the fields are getting mixed up.  Any solution other than manually tweaking the migration files?

Correct renames in migration file manually. EF Core cannot track Visual Studio's renames it just suggest it's own vision and probably wrong in your case. It is normal behaviour to correct migration file manually.

Solutions

Separate Migrations for Each Rename
Create individual migrations for each rename operation. This ensures EF Core processes one change at a time and reduces the likelihood of conflicts or mix-ups.


dotnet ef migrations add RenameFieldA
dotnet ef database update
dotnet ef migrations add RenameFieldB
dotnet ef database update

Use Explicit Mapping
When renaming fields, explicitly define the old and new names in the migration script. This removes ambiguity.

Can you give me an example of explicit mapping?
